# 18 boys and 2 girls are made to stand in a random order.Let X be the number of boys standing in between two girls .

Tags: probability, combinatorics

18 boys and 2 girls are made to stand in a random order.Let X be the number of boys standing in between two girls .

Find $ P(X=5).$

Initially i thought that the distribution is uniform , but unfortunately it is not.

Here is what i did :-

Ways to select 5 boys from 18 $=$ $18\choose 5$

The denominator then becomes=$\displaystyle\sum_{18}^{i=0}$$ 18\choose i $$=2^{18}\Rightarrow P(X=5)=\frac{18\choose 5}{2^{18}}$

But the answer is $\frac{14}{190}$ .How do i get this answer (if it is correct!)??

Comment: Can you help me too?)) What is the flow in this logic? Assume that there are 20 seats that form a circle. First girl choose the seat at random with prob. 1/20. In this case there remain 19 seats for the 2 girl. But if we want to have 5 boys between them we eliminate the adjacent 5 seats too. Hence, there are 14 seats for second girl and she must seat in the “corner” seat or that is in the 14th seat. It can happen with prob. 1/14. But it doesn’t matter from which side we will eliminate the 5 seats so 2/14. So the overall probability is 2/20*2/14. Since it doesn’t matter which girl is the first.

Comment: First of all. Dont think of them as arranged in a circle.They are arranged in a line . If I correctly follow your statement. , 1st girl can be placed in 20 ways. " First girl choose the seat at random with prob. 1/20"<- This statement is wrong. A girl gets a seat in one of  those 20 places. with probability of 1. So your reasoning doesnot work here. If the girl had to choose a specified seat(eg seat no. 7 ) then the probability would be $\frac{1}{20}$ and thus the process would be very long. In order to avoid such things, we consider orderings/permutations to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The denominator is ${20 \choose 2} = 190$: there are $20$ total boys and girls, and if you number the positions $1$ through $20$, then there are two positions out of those $20$ total for the two girls to stand.

The numerator is $14$: there are $14$ ways for two girls to have $5$ boys in between: they can have positions $1$ and $7$, or $2$ and $8$ ... all the way to $14$ and $20$

Comment: @DonielF Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Thank you for the solution. However i dont understand why my process didnt work?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is wrong with your method. I assume you are using the following method: to find the probability of an event $E$ in a sample space $S$ where **every outcome is equally likely**, the answer is $|E|/|S|$. A common mistake is choosing the probability space incorrectly so that not all outcomes are equally likely.

In your denominator, you have $2^{18}$, implying that your probability space $S$ consists of all $2^{18}$ choices for the subset of boys to go between the girls. The problem is that not all of these choices are equally likely, so that $|E|/|S|$ method does not work.

In this problem, we assume that the boys and girls are standing in a random order. This means we should assume all $20!$ orderings of the people are equally likely, so these orderings should be our sample space, $S$. (There are other valid choices, as in Bram28's answer). Therefore, we must count **orderings** where there are 5 boys between the girls. This is more information than you calculated; you only specified which boys go in the middle.